# Linux merging files

Tags: linux, command

I'm doing a linux online course but im stuck with a question, you can find the question below.

You will get three files called `a.bf`, `b.bf` and `c.bf`. Merge the contents of these three files and write it to a new file called abc.bf. Respect the order: abc.bf must contain the contents of a.bf first, followed by those of b.bf, followed by those of c.bf.

Example
Suppose the given files have the following contents:

a.bf contains +++.

b.bf contains [][][][].

c.bf contains <><><>.

The file abc.bf should then have

```
+++[][][][]<><><>
```

as its content.
I know how to merge the 3 files but when i use cat my output is:

```
+++
[][][]
<><><>
```

When i use paste my output is `"+++ 'a lot of spaces' [][][][] 'a lot of spaces' <><><>"`

My output that i need is `+++[][][][]<><><>`, i dont want the spaces between the content. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is delete the newline characters.

With `tr`:

```
cat {a,b,c}.bf | tr --delete '\n' > abc.bf
```

With `echo` & `sed`:

```
echo $(cat {a,b,c}.bf) | sed -E 's/ //g' > abc.bf
```

With `xargs` & `sed`:

```
<{a,b,c}.bf xargs | sed -E 's/ //g' > abc.bf
```

Note that `sed` is only used to remove the spaces.

With `cat` & `sed`:

```
cat {a,b,c}.bf | sed -z 's/\n//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

`echo -n "$(cat a.bf)$(cat b.bf)$(cat c.bf)" > abc.bf`

- echo `-n` will not output trailing newlines